# How to get field time from database

Tags: database, go

I have a problem retrieving data in the database. why insert with different output results at `created_at` and `updated_at`?

I am still a beginner for Go programming

Struct:

```
type Builder struct {
     Id         int       `json:"id"`
     Name       string    `json:"name"`
     Created_at time.Time `json:"created_at"`
     Updated_at time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

DB :

```
CREATE TABLE test_types (
    id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE now(),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO test_types (id, name, created_at) VALUES (1, 'Welcome Screen', '2019-03-23 00:00:00');
```

with the following results:

```
insert : 2019-03-23 00:00:00

output : “0001-01-01T00:00:00Z”
```

why is it different between inserts and outputs, is it parsing my data incorrectly?

Comment: Could you please also provide a code for inserting and fetching results?

Comment: What is the pattern you're using for that 'timestamp'? It is not RFC3339, which it looks like it's being expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert date like this

"2022-01-09T00:00:00Z"

or

"1996-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"